# Issue with Dionysus Build/make on Mac OS X 10.10 yosemite

Tags: python, c++, macos, serialization, boost

I followed to instructions for to make/build Dionysus from http://www.mrzv.org/software/dionysus/get-build-install.html

From a brand new computer with nothing, 
I used port to install python27 , cmake, boost, mercurial and a few other packages. 
In terminal I then did

```
hg clone http://hg.mrzv.org/Dionysus/
cd Dionysus
hg up tip
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

When the terminal is running through the make it has the following error:

```
  [  1%] Built target bottleneck-distance
  [  3%] Building CXX object  
 examples/alphashapes/CMakeFiles/alphashapes2d.dir/alphashapes2d.o
 In file included from   
/Users/pavan/Desktop/Dionysus/examples/alphashapes/alphashapes2d.cpp:3:
In file included from   
/Users/pavan/Desktop/Dionysus/examples/alphashapes/alphashapes2d.h:12:
In file included from   
/Users/pavan/Desktop/Dionysus/include/topology/simplex.h:221:

In file included from   
/Users/pavan/Desktop/Dionysus/include/topology/simplex.hpp:2:

In file included from /opt/local/include/boost/serialization/set.hpp:26: 

/opt/local/include/boost/serialization/detail/stack_constructor.hpp:54:31:     error: 
  no member named 'load_construct_data_adl' in namespace
  'boost::serialization'
    boost::serialization::load_construct_data_adl(
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
make[2]: ***         [examples/alphashapes/CMakeFiles/alphashapes2d.dir/alphashapes2d.o] 
Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/alphashapes/CMakeFiles/alphashapes2d.dir/all] 
Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So far I've tried everything I can think of, reinstalled all boost and python dependencies (started from a brand new factory reset computer). I'm a complete noob when it comes to anything C related so any pointers would be extremely appreciated.

Also, I tried the same exact install on my ubuntu loaded pc and it worked, so I'm wondering if the port install feature is creating some issues?

Comment: Which version of `boost` are you using?

Comment: I ran into this same issue trying to build [rtabmap](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Installation) for mac. @Deviacium's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled across the same problem. Also using OSX 10.10. A few days switching and manipulating libraries between macports and brew with no success...

Today I finally compiled Dionysus with boost this way:

```
brew unlink boost
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install boost155
brew link boost155
```

Yet have to see if the whole library tree (boost, cgal, swig, cgal-swig-bindings, dionysus) builds well..

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that version 155 specifically is what was going to work? I'm curious so that I can find out how to fix this sort of problem on my own next time. +1 for a working answer. Also, I had to use `brew link --force boost155` for the last step. #osx10.11.3

Comment: Around that time i knew the reason... Now i don't exactly remember. Might be something with dependency search in cgal or dionysus - it could not find the latest boost... or something like that.. A good reminder to write deeper explanations for the future =)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I simply removed the explicit namespace (in stack_constructor.hpp):

```
load_construct_data_adl
```

instead of

```
boost::serialization::load_construct_data_adl
```

this solved the error in my case.